# angular material md-select - e2e protractor tests - element not visible

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, e2e-testing

I wanted to test the md-select component and I'm stuck on clicking the md-option, that return an error:

```
Failed: element not visible
```

I tried to follow the instructions from this article : https://thecattlecrew.net/2015/03/05/automated-ui-tests-for-an-angularjs-material-select-item-with-protractor/. My test code look like:

```
element( by.model('vm.model') ).click(); //ok, the select is opened
browser.waitForAngular(); // also tried with browser.driver.sleep(5000);
element( by.css('.md-select-menu-container md-option[value="6"]')).click();
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Is there anyone who has struggled already with md-select e2e tests ?

Comment: I will just add that the browsers widow is full screen and that the option that I want to click exist and is visible (no need to scroll the list). I also tried the solution with promise then function likeelement(...).click().then(()=>{…}). I also tried to simplify things to maximum and do somethig like `element( by.tagName('md-option')).click();` but I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my css selector returned more then one result, 2 results to be precise. I couldn't verify where is the second md-option. However I narrowed my selector by adding md-active class and now it works correctly.

Here is my full code:

```
element( by.model('vm.model') ).click(); 
browser.waitForAngular(); 
element( by.css('.md-select-menu-container.md-active md-option[value="6"]')).click();
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note if you get here and want to select a non-visible option. For me it throw an exception but after adding the el.isPresent() check it became selectable for some reason:

```
static async mdSelectByModelContainingText(model: string, text: string) {
    await element(by.model(model)).click();
    await browser.waitForAngular(); 

    let el = element(by.cssContainingText('.md-select-menu-container.md-active md-option > div.md-text', text));
    if (!(await el.isPresent())) {
        throw Error('Not clickable');
    }
    await el.click();
    await browser.waitForAngular(); 
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice solution I would suggest to use `await browser.sleep(xxx)` before that way if there are some loading that way it would find the element

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the css selector cant locate md-option. i think this will help

```
element( by.model('vm.model') ).click(); 
browser.waitForAngular();
element( by.css('.md-select-menu-container.md-active md-select-menu>* md-option[value='6'].md-checkbox-enabled]')).click();
browser.waitForAngular();
```